# I can't install VirtualBox on my Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, virtualbox, installation

I can't install VirtualBox 5.0.10 on my Windows 7.

I tried almost everything, but when I run the setup, halfway through it stops and shows this message just like in the image below:

[image]

> Source file not found:
>   C\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\VirtualBox\common.cab. 
>   Verify that the file exists and that you can access it.

These are some of the things I tried but didn't work.

1. Run As Administrator
2. Delete program and reinstall
3. Change MAXNUM filter from 8 to 20

Please help.

Comment: Try to grant full control to SYSTEM group on your %temp% directory

Comment: Maybe the installer is corrupted. try to redownload it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The installer might be getting tripped up on non-ASCII characters in paths. Try creating a new user account with a name that contains only English letters and running the installer there. The other account will need to be an administrator. You can remove it after you're done.

Comment: Wow. Thanks!  That worked! How can i move the program to the existing user account after?

Comment: @user523246 I'm fairly certain VirtualBox installs for all users on the computer. If no shortcut appears for you in your main account, you can manually make a shortcut to `\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBox.exe`.